# Lookup MIN value in a column based on two criteria from two other columns in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I have an Excel spreadsheet with ~60,000 rows of data. I am trying to lookup the minimum value while two criteria are satisfied. My data is structured as shown below:

[image]

I have the following formula which works on the first 20 rows of data:

```
=MIN(IF(($I$1:$I$20=1)*($J$1:$J$20=1),$H$1:$H$20))
```

This formula correctly returns 0.05 as the minimum rank value when (seq index=1, allele index=1). However, when I try to extend the formula for the entire dataset I do not get back correct values. I use:

```
=MIN(IF(($I:$I=1)*($J:$J=1),$H:$H))
```

and I should get back 0.05 for (seq index=1,allele index=1), 0.07 for (seq index=2, allele index=1), 0.09 for (seq index=3, allele index=1). I have 1000 indexes for 30 or so alleles and so a very large dataset of 60,000+ rows. I would like to populate a matrix in a separate sheet that reads columns I and J and calculates the minimum for certain criteria. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: what do you get back?  And did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: @ScottCraner 0.01

Comment: @spyros there is probably some data in those 60,000 rows you didn't expect, and 0.01 is the correct answer. Try filtering on the 1/1 criteria and inspect the result.  BTW, `MINIFS` would be a better function to use, if you have a recent version of Excel

Comment: given that you have a large data set with a high level of duplicated entries, I would recommend you to create a pivot table first to show the MIN rank for each combination of seq and allele index, and then do the look up from the pivot table. Your MIN formula should work just have to make sure to confirm it by pressing **CSE** and try to refer to the exact range of data instead of referring to the whole column in your formula.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and sorry for being late to reply.